# How to set up an app icon for a Command Line Tool written with Xcode and C++?

Tags: xcode, icons, wxwidgets, apple-developer

I am on OSX 12.2, and XCode 13.2.1. I created successfully a Command-line tool app written in C++ and wxwidgets library to add the GUI interface. I inserted the images for the app icon in Images > AppIcon, see the screenshot attached. However, when I run the app there is a 'blank' icon as shown in the second screenshot attached.

How may I get the desired icon to appear ?

Thanks!

[image: blank icon]

[image: app images for icons]

Comment: I'm not sure what your application is - a Command Line Tool or a GUI application. Therefore I can't help you with the issue.

Comment: It is a Command Line Tool written in C++. In this C++ code, I include the wxWidgets libarry, which is a GUI library.

Comment: if its a command line tool it doesn't need an icon. You will start it from the Terminal anyway.

Comment: Well, the fact that it does not need an icon does not mean that I don't want to set an icon on its clickable app, just read the original post.

Comment: @Pascal did you figure out how to do it?